# What's the beefiest front shock (26"), avail in quick release, with travel of 100-125mm (no more)?

Tags: mountain-bike, fork, suspension

Details:  I mostly enjoy XC and all mountain riding. However, I also from time to time, will go out with friends on some much more intense downhill trails.   I'm also about 240 pounds, give or take.    So, while I really really like my bike, and the geometry is fine (as far as I'm concerned) even for some downhill.   The fork I'm running now is an older Fox 125 RL. But, being 245# and bombing downhill really makes me nervous.  Since my bike is pretty high-end (titanium fame, King/Thomson/Race Face.....etc), I'd like to just (if possible....and maybe it isn't) add a really, really solid fork up front.  Weight it not an issue (for obvious reasons).  Geometry obviously is, as the bike is designed for 80-100 travel up front.  I go 125....but that's it.   Is there such a thing as a fork with 36mm or larger uppers with only 125mm or less travel??

Hope I can turn this xc bike into one that can handle **anything** thrown at it with my 245# riding.   ??

Answer (score 1):

You could look into dirt jump forks, such as the [Marzocchi Dirt Jump](http://www.marzocchi.com/template/detailProdotti.asp?LN=UK&idIU=2464&idC=1561&IdFolder=113&uf=IU&IdOggetto=59714) or the [RockShox Argyle](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=rockshox%20argyle&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=10314830879467022504&sa=X&ei=Lm8GT4H0NsSTiQKchNkh&ved=0CDoQ8wIwAQ).  There aren't too many options left for burly forks with 9mm quick release drop-outs.

Honestly though, Fox makes some nice forks.  Email their support and describe your use case (avoiding terms like 'hucking' or '6 foot drop to flat' unless applicable).

I would be more worried about an XC frame and wheelset failing than a modern suspension fork from a reputable brand.

Comment: Thanks folks!  I went with a manitou minute.  Got a crazy deal. I think it'll be fine.   The rims in all honesty are probably the weak link.  Frame is titanium, so it's bomb proof.  Hubs are king...so they're fine.  Thanks Again for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

The fox shox are really hard to beat. I was 230 at one point and really threw a lot at my RL.

Keep the air pressure up to the right PSI for your weight and lube those stanchions with a teflon lube. You'll get a decade of use out of that fork.

Answer (score 0):

Fox forks are much better now they've beefed up the skewer to something similar to rockshox's maxle and I'd say that you'd benefit from having something like that.

Rockshox's pike comes with a 20mm maxle and stiffens the forks up no end.

I don't know what hubs you're running but plenty of hubs now have conversion kits to go from QR to a maxle.